# Android Layout Inflater

Tags: android

I am trying to get a id from different xml file and i am tring to use inflater for that but it doesn't work. I have searched a lot but it didn't help me about by code

This is my code;

```
            final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.tab1, null);
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image = (ImageView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

in this code I am getting the last photo which I took from sd card and I want to post this photo to the image view in a different xml. My code doesn't throw exeption but it does not post the image to the image view

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that thumbnail contains data?

Comment: yes the problem is not thumbnail because it works when i use the same xml . I need to correct the inflater part

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted here will inflate the XML to a View, look for an image View in that View with the id of R.id.imageView1, then set the image bitmap.

If this is all you do, this inflated view (textEntryView) will never be seen as it has not been added as a child to another view, nor is it added as content for an activity context.

Comment: I think i get what are you saying should i implement view as imageview i tried it but it started to trow exeption. do i need to implement anything at android manifest while using this?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are successfully creating textEntryView but without seeing more of your code, we have no idea what you are doing with it.  If you don't do something with the view it will not be seen.  Calling inflate by itself will not make a view visible.

Comment: ImageView image= (ImageView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab1,null).findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);    //what is wrong in here i tried to correct it . it does not give null exeption but does not work